# Sort an array by object field

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects

> const myarray = [   {
> name: 'Alex',
> job: 'Doctor'   },   {
> name: 'John',
> job: 'Taxi Driver'   },   {
> name: 'Marc',
> job: 'Taxi Driver'   }, ]

How can i, for each job, print the name of the job, then all the corresponding objects ?

For example I want to be able to display:

Doctor:
Alex

Taxi driver:
John,
Marc

Comment: What does sorting have to do with this? What have you attempted. It is a simple loop and reading the properties of the object and outputting it in some way.

Comment: @epascarello I am sorry, my english is not very good i didn't know what other word i could use to explain the problem that's why i wrote and example of what i am trying to achieve. Your comment was not of much help but thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
const myarray = [ { name: 'Alex', job: 'Doctor' }, { name: 'John', job: 'Taxi Driver' }, { name: 'Marc', job: 'Taxi Driver' } ]
const sorted = {}
myarray.forEach((e)=>{
  if(e.job in sorted){
    sorted[e.job].push(e.name);
  }else{
    sorted[e.job] = [e.name]
  }
})
console.log(sorted);
```

To print them in the format you want:

```js
const myarray = [ { name: 'Alex', job: 'Doctor' }, { name: 'John', job: 'Taxi Driver' }, { name: 'Marc', job: 'Taxi Driver' } ]
const sorted = {}
myarray.forEach((e)=>{
  if(e.job in sorted){
    sorted[e.job].push(e.name);
  }else{
    sorted[e.job] = [e.name]
  }
})
for(const key in sorted){
  var str = key+': ';
  sorted[key].forEach(e=>str+=e+', ');
  console.log(str.slice(0, -2));
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! That's exactly what i needed. Thanks for your help

Comment: @LooGie No problem. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

first of all create object which will store job like `obj = {"Taxi driver": [],"Doctor": [] }` and after you can pass array `myarray.forEach(e => obj[e.job].append(e.name))` after just manipulate with object. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

It returns an object with the result you want

```js
const myarray = [ { name: 'Alex', job: 'Doctor' }, { name: 'John', job: 'Taxi Driver' }, { name: 'Marc', job: 'Taxi Driver' }, ]

function getJobs() {
  let result = {};
  myarray.forEach(function t(e) {
    if (!result.hasOwnProperty(e.job))  result[e.job] = [];
    result[e.job].push(e.name);
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(getJobs());
```